# Что появилось раньше(,) курица или яйцо?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Это один из "вечных вопросов философии", но сейчас не о вечном.

**Вариантов написания вопроса четыре**: без знака препинания, с запятой, с тире, с двоеточием.

Существуют и другие вариации, например:
 **Кто** появился раньше — курица или яйцо?
 **Кто (что)** появилось раньше: курица или яйцо?  (Е. Шугаев)

**А как правильно задать и написать этот вопрос?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Выбираем вариант с тире: **КтО** появился раньше — **курица или яйцО**?

Здесь "кто" — обобщающее слово, "курица или яйцо" — однородный ряд, поэтому желательно **выделить их логическим ударением.**

2) **Двоеточие** можно использовать, но интонация будет другая: Кто появился рАньше: курица или яйцо? Понижение тона перед однородным рядом, предупредительная пауза, ударение на слове "раньше".

3) **Вариант с запятой** "Кто появился раньше, курица или яйцо?" теоретически возможен только потому, что при наличии одиночного союза ИЛИ мы имеем единую фразу "курица или яйцо" (в этом случае эту конструкцию можно рассматривать как пояснительную). Сравнить: Кто пойдёт, я или ты? **Вариант упрощенный, разговорный**, безо всяких пауз, для вечного философского вопроса не подойдет.

4) **Вариант  без знаков** вообще ненормативен.

**Выбор кто/что**

Здесь, действительно, встречаются варианты, но по частотности, кажется, лидирует **местоимение ЧТО**. Объяснить **это можно  значением обобщенности вопроса и возможностью согласования со средним родом**: что появилось. В этом случае  мы **не обозначаем одушевленность и не решаем вопрос заранее.**

Местоимение КТО как раз этот вопрос решает, его употребление можно объяснить формальным согласованием с ближайшим одушевленным существительным, а это не слишком заметный и влиятельный фактор.

Поэтому окончательно выбираем вариант: **ЧтО появилось раньше — курица или яйцО?**

Comment: Почему Вы выбрали КТО, а не ЧТО?

Comment: Спасибо за поправки и за вопрос, сначала я как-то не обратила на него внимания.